# OsCommerce - Custom URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, oscommerce

I understand there are a few SEO plugins for OsCommerce, however none of theme seem to allow me to specify a custom slug for a product.

Essentially, I want to rewrite this:

```
http://www.example.com/category/nice-product-slug
```

to the default url:

```
http://www.example.com/product_info.php?products_id=29
```

I can obviously do this in `.htaccess` but I can't find a way to make OsCommerce generate the Product URLs (for navs, sidebars, product grids, etc) in the way I need.

Anyone have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily if you install the following addons (which are pretty much a necessity for SEO anyway).  After installation just look in admin->configuration->SEO URLs and it will be obvious how to make your URL's just the way you want them.  I think the setting you will want to enable is "Enable use Header Tags SEO as name"... But there are a few other setting in SEO URLs that don't use Header Tags SEO that may be acceptable to you too.

Ultimate SEO URLs: http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/2823

and

Header Tags SEO: http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/5851/